# is there an way to stop moving pos2 to pos1 after moved it?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm working on drag and drop 2d educational game and I'm stuck with this code.
When I try to pos1 to pos2 it works. However, I am able to it again from pos2 to pos1 which I don't want.
I tried some code but got some errors
Is it possible to solve this this with `PointerEventData`?

```
public class Manager : MonoBehaviour, IBeginDragHandler, IDragHandler, IEndDragHandler
{
    Vector2 pos1;
    public GameObject pos2;

    void Start()
    {
        pos1 = transform.position;
    }

    public void OnBeginDrag(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        debug.log(eventData)
    }
    public void OnDrag(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        transform.position = Input.mousePosition;
    }
    public void OnEndDrag(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        float distance = Vector3.Distance(transform.position, pos2.transform.position);
        if (distance < 50)
        {
            transform.position = pos2.transform.position;
            transform.localScale = pos2.transform.localScale;
        }
        else
        {
            transform.position = pos1;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So, once it has been dragged to the right spot, you don't want to be able to drag it again? Have you considered a boolean flag to prevent further dragging?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here, I re-wrote you code to include a bool that limits when the object can and can't be moved.

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;

public class Manager : MonoBehaviour, IBeginDragHandler, IDragHandler, IEndDragHandler
{
Vector2 pos1;
public GameObject pos2;
private bool canMove;

void Start()
{
    pos1 = transform.position;
    canMove = true;
}

public void OnBeginDrag(PointerEventData eventData)
{
    Debug.Log(eventData);
}

public void OnDrag(PointerEventData eventData)
{
    if (canMove)
        transform.position = Input.mousePosition;

}

public void OnEndDrag(PointerEventData eventData)
{
    float distance = Vector3.Distance(transform.position, pos2.transform.position);
    if (distance < 50)
    {

        transform.position = pos2.transform.position;
        transform.localScale = pos2.transform.localScale;
        canMove = false;
    }
    else
    {
        transform.position = pos1;
    }
}

}
```

Comment: i tried it befor but with out


  if (canMove)
        transform.position = Input.mousePosition;
thank you alot its working :D.